# Laravel keeping track of notifications

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, notifications, eloquent

I have a field in my `budgets` table called `reports`. When adding a new budget, in my form, I have three checkboxes. The value of these checkboxes will be saved as an array in my reports field:

```
["website","email","push"]
```

Using commands and events, I am sending out notifications every night for the ones that are found in this array. I want to send a report only once.

The issue is, how to keep track if a notification has been sent already with this setup? I want to refrain from having too many fields in my database, like:

```
email_reports
email_reports_notified
```

...and so on.

Any help is appreciated, also if there is a better way of handling this.

Comment: To keep things organised you can have a `notifications` table and relate it to various notifiable entities via polymorphic relationships.

Comment: Thank you, I actually have that table setup and using that would actually make things a lot better organised indeed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And while I was doing something else, I just thought of the most simple solution, to created a `notified` field and adding the values there in an array as well..